# JavaScript code for downloading image from server

Tags: javascript

I have a web page. On clicking the download button, the image which is stored in the server should be downloaded to the local system. Can anyone provide the JavaScript code for this?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript code is simple:

```
document.location = "http://ImageUrlHere";
```

The server side code is the "complicated" part.

http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html

Add the following HTTP Header to the response:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.jpg`

Comment: can we do this without server side scripting?

Comment: Uuuhh... you may be able to do it through IIS or Apache configuration on particular files.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody will provide you the code but I can give you the idea of doing this.

First get the image path using Ajax in JavaScript.

Set image src from this JavaScript method by passing the image path along with the servlet name where you have code for displaying image.

Comment: but it will only display the image. He want to save the image in local system